# Invoking Ruby Scripts or Executables on on-premise server using Azure Data Factory v2?

Tags: ruby, azure, azure-data-factory, azure-batch

How can I invoke Ruby scripts or executable(s) on on-premise server using Azure Data Factory v2 (ADF)? In my view, it falls under the category of Custom Activity and ADF as of now supports custom activity only via Azure Batch and Azure HDInsight. But what about running custom activity on on-premise server/network?
It's understandable that for on-premise server or networks behind firewall, one needs to setup self-hosted integration run-time (IR). But as per documentation of ADF, it appears that self-hosted IR can be used for copy activity. Can I run a custom activity on self-hosted integration run-time?

one workaround can be that I use Azure Batch that SSH into my on-premise server and executes the scripts but due to certain security restrictions, I cant proceed with this possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

Azure batch linked service can also reference a selfhosted IR. So you should be able to run a custom activity on selfhosted integration runtime. 
You could use [ADF UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-portal) to have a try.

Comment: The way I understand is that to run a custom activity in on-premise via self-hosted integration run-time, Azure Batch will have to be provisioned first and once provisioned, it can access the self-hosted run-time? Is that understanding correct? 
The issue, as I highlighted before, that in our current setup, inbound connections originating from Cloud isn't allowed from security point of view.
I am looking for a solution wherein we don't need to rely on Azure Batch and somehow a custom activity could be run directly on self-hosted IR

Comment: Yes, you are right. And according to my understanding, azure batch is inevitable for custom activity. I believe you have read this doc. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity  Hope others could give a better solution.